# How to get device type / os from fcm registration token

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-cloud-messaging

How can I get the device type or operating system from an FCM registration token on my app server, or can I make a post request to my app server with the registration token and user_id?

Reason is, I want to programmatically be able to send messages only to certain usersegments like I can in the firebase console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Information about the device cannot be extracted from the FCM instance ID token.

You will have to set up your own stream of the information from the client to your servers, where you can then combine it with the FCM token to target users. Not incidentally, this is what Firebase itself does too (through Google Analytics) and is what powers the targeting in the Firebase console.